# CircleCI - Git could not resolve host when cloning repository

Tags: docker, npm-install, circleci

When running npm install within circleci we fetch some node packages from our github repositories through package.json. This operation is happening when building a docker image from a Dockerfile.

This has been working great until last week when without changes in our side, we started to get errors while cloning these packages. To perform this operation, we were using Basic Authentication in the URL providing user credentials in it. For ie:

```
https://<username>:<password>@github.com/elektron-technogoly/<repository>.git
```

Now, we get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone ...
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://<username>:<password>@github.com/elektron-technogoly/<repository>.git': 
Could not resolve host: <username>
```

From the error message it seems like it thinks the username is the host and thus, fails. I checked that password is still valid and it did not expire.

Has recently - around last week - something changed that could cause this error? Has Basic Authentication been disabled?

*UPDATE*: Playing a bit seems like when you change the base docker image (say from *node:4-slim* to *node:4*), the first time it works, subsequent times don't. Unfortunately, logs are not giving me any lead, both look exactly the same but the error appears from the first onwards.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try `git config --global --unset https.proxy` and see if that helps

Comment: @henrik CircleCI is the one running my builds so I do not have a clue about their infrastructure. Anyway, I tried to add that command in my Dockerfile but it returned: `The command '/bin/sh -c git config --global --unset https.proxy' returned a non-zero code: 5`

Comment: The `non-zero code: 5` depends on the platform that runs the command. Which platform do you run this command on? On windows I think it represents an "Access denied".

Comment: CircleCi uses Linux so I guess that is what it is running on.